# Smooth CSS 2D Transformations using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I recently came across this website http://www.smartusa.com/
This has an awesome scrolling effect and smooth scaling of elements.

Can anyone help me figure out the logic used to achieve the smooth scaling effect? Not the prallax scrolling but the scaling of the cars.

I tried `jQuery.Transition.js` plugin and added a scroll event but the transformation is quite jumpy. Its nowhere as smooth as the effect in the site above. I stopped queuing and reduced the duration to 10ms but still its not good enough.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try TransformJS - it uses CSS3 3D Transforms (even if you only animate one or two dimensions) in order to force the browser to hardware accelerate the animations when the hardware is available.

http://transformjs.strobeapp.com/

It also integrates into jQuery nicely.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried the above library.  It's all good except that the scroll event is messing up the whole thing. Everytime i drag the scroll bar, the event is fired multiple times and this is causing the animation to continue[queue] even after i stop scrolling.

As you can see in the SmartUsa website, the scaling effect is super smooth without any jumps.

Comment: You'll definitely want to debounce/throttle the handler. You don't need to run it each time the event fires, just fast enough to seem responsive. Ben Alman has a good plugin for this: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the plugin you are using:
https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki

but with an animation library like that, you would do something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ $('.example').transform({rotate: e.scrollTop }); });
```